# Groovy script: How to parse/format Json in groovy in each loop

Tags: javascript, json, groovy, scripting, soapui

I am new on Groovy, I am trying to mock a service in soap ui.

Requirement is to load a text file with json data, and load a node with matching data.

whati have tried is as below,

```
def inputFile = new File("D:\\Users\\json.txt")
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)

    InputJSON.each{  
        def ID1 = it
        it.items.each { 
            if(it.Number == itemNumber) 
            {
                log.info it
                requestContext.Id = ID1
            } 
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine just one issue, is the format.
when ID1 loads into requestContext.Id, the format of json is lost from the file.

What I need is

```
{
 "items" {
        "number" : 1475175072691
      }
}
```

what i get is

```
{
 metadata = {
        timestamp = 1475175072691
}
}
```

Why does it take away the double quotes **"** and colon **:** from my json.
Please suggest.

Comment: show that contents of the file, please?

Comment: Content of the file is same as what I have mentioned in "What I need" section, when I read it from file and log it, I get what I see in the "What i get is" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def str = '''\
[
   {
      "items":{
         "number":1475175072691
      }
   },
   {
      "items":{
         "number":1475175072691
      }
   },
   {
      "items":{
         "number":1475175072691
      }
   },
   {
      "items":{
         "number":1475175072691
      }
   }
]'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)

json.each { 
  println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(it))
}
```

prints out the following result:

```
{
    "items": {
        "number": 1475175072691
    }
}
{
    "items": {
        "number": 1475175072691
    }
}
{
    "items": {
        "number": 1475175072691
    }
}
{
    "items": {
        "number": 1475175072691
    }
}
```

In other words, you need to serialize and pretty print the json nodes to get the format you want.

Comment: additional information: the runtime type of the `json` variable (original code `InputJSON`) is `java.util.Map`. Printing a Map results in quotes being stripped from String literals. Using `JsonOutput.prettyPrint` turns a Map of values into its corresponding JSON.

Comment: Thanks folks for help.